# Not able to find image in external path in Sikuli

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

Can anyone help me with the below error message ?
[image: error image]

Comment: Please read the *"Help others reproduce the problem"* section of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It appears thant '\a' in image path string is interpreted as [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). Try using forward slashes in path, or properly escaping backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [guest-4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998157/guest-418)18 for pointing out the issue, after I changed the code to

```html
doubleClick(r"D:\Users\alapati.n\Pictures\Screenshots\Screenshot (12).png")
```

it worked